# From group isomorphisms to algebra isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $A$ be an algebra and let $A^{\ast}$ be the subset of units (that is, invertible elements) of $A$. Then $A^{\ast}$ is a group under the multiplication of $A$.

Let $f^{\ast}:A^{\ast}\to A^{\ast}$ be a group isomorphism. Is it true that there always exists an isomorphism (between algebras; so it preserves addition and multiplication structure) $f:A\to A$ such that $f|_{A^{\ast}}=f^{\ast}$? If yes, is such $f$ unique?

Comment: Such $f$ is not unique, since $x \rightarrow rx$, $r > 0$, is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ extending the identity isomorphism of the group of units.

Comment: @baharampuri This doesn't seem right, since $x\mapsto rx$ is not multiplicative for $r\neq 1$. Anyway, in the same spirit, the map $f(x)\mapsto f(x+1)$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which extends the identity of the group of units, so the extension of a group isomorphism of $A^*$ to $A$, even if it exists, is not unique in general.

Comment: @Questioner sorry I don't see why $\phi: x \rightarrow rx$ is not multiplicative. Consider $\mathbb{R}[rx]$ and it's the evaluation map where we are evaluating at $rx$. And since $r >0$ it has real $n$th root for all $n$ hence it is surjective. Or simply: $\phi(f(x)g(x))=f(rx)g(rx)=\phi(f(x))\phi(g(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

First this looks like a statement on rings rather than a statement over algebras. Anyway, take $A$ to be the field with $5$ elements. Then $A^*$ is a cyclic group with $4$ elements, it admits one non-trivial automorphism $f^*$. However if $f$ is an automorphism of ring then it must $1$ to $1$ but this implies that $f$ is the identity. Hence no ring automorphism can extend $f^*$.

Comment: How does this imply that $f$ is the identity exactly? There exist rings with nontrivial automorphisms and they all send $1$ to $1$.

Comment: Yes, but there is only one non-trivial (group) automorphism of the group $\Bbb F_5^{\ast}$ (namely:$ x \mapsto x^{-1}$) and this does not extend to an (additive) homomorphism of $\Bbb F_5$, which is *completely* determined by $f(1)$. IN other words, this happens because $\Bbb F_5$ is *special*, being a cyclic ring.

Comment: @MattSamuel, I could have chosen any field of cardinal $p>2$. They all are generated by $1$ additively. This forces any ring automorphism to be trivial. I have never said that this is true for any ring.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\mathbb{R}$ algebra $\mathbb{R}$ the group of units $U=\mathbb{R}^*$. Let us take the automorphism of $U$ which send $x $ to $\frac{1}{x}$. Now this does not extend to an algebra automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ since any such morphism will send 1 to 1 and hence will fix the rationals. Where in this map the non-zero rationals are sent to it's inverse.